# How to change the position of menu items on actionbar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, menuitem

I'm developing one application in which I have to add a custom layout on actionbar. Adding the custom layout is done, but when I'm adding the menu items on actionbar my custom layout changes it's position from right of the actionbar to center of the actionbar. Below is the image what I have achieved so far.

[image: Done till here]

I want something like this on the actionbar.

[image: Like this]

Custom layout(yellow button) at the right most part of actionbar and menu items in the middle.

Adding my code to achieve this custom layout using native android actionbar:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    cView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.header, null);
    actionBar.setCustomView(cView);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.websearch_menu, menu);
    return true;

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {

    case android.R.id.home:
        finish();

    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

How can this be achieved?

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you are setting your custom view as a custom view in the action bar. If you are using ActionbarSherlock you can instead add the custom view as a normal menu item and set an action view for it using `.setActionView(yourCustomView or yourCustomLayoutId)`. You can then set `.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS)` to display the view. Just make sure your custom view is set to width `wrap_content` or otherwise it will push the other menu items off the screen. This might also work without ActionbarSherlock, but I haven't tried it there yet.

EDIT: Try modifying your `onCreateOptionsMenu` method

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.websearch_menu, menu);

    // add this
    menu.add(Menu.NONE, 0, Menu.NONE, "custom")
        .setActionView(R.layout.header)
        .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);

    return true;
}
```

and remove this from your onCreate method

```
actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
cView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.header, null);
actionBar.setCustomView(cView);
```

EDIT:

If you need to reference the views from your custom layout, you can do this in your `onCreateOptionsMenu` method as follows (note: I wrote this code in the browser, so no guarantee that I didn't make a typo or something):

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // inflate the menu and add the item with id viewId,
    // which has your layout as actionview

    View actionView = menu.getItem(viewId).getActionView();
    View viewFromMyLayout = actionView.findViewById(R.id.viewFromMyLayout);

    // here you can set listeners to your view or store a reference 
    // to it somewhere, so you can use it later

    return true;
}
```

Comment: I have added the code how to do this with ActionbarSherlock, I hope it is the same with the default Actionbar

Comment: You rocked dude. Thank you so much, you saved me from creating a complete custom layout and then inflating it to the actionbar. Thanx!

Comment: @Thrakbad How does it change the order of the items on the actionBar exactly? I don't understand.

Comment: @Thrakbad Can we give some margin from left to the menu item, so that, it completely be in the middle of the actionbar?

Comment: @androiddeveloper The items are just added from left to right, so the item added last will be the one to the right (except for the overflow menu)

Comment: @Anupam I think this would only be possible with a complete custom layout

Comment: @Thrakbad This is interesting. How do you use your own custom layout for the action bar? is it this "actionBar.setCustomView(cView);" ?

Comment: That is one option, if you set a custom view with the width `match_parent` and add no menu items you will have your custom view over the whole action bar. Another solution is to add only one menu item and set the custom view as its actionView much like I did in the example above.

Comment: @Thrakbad Cool. Thanks. Good to know. Hope I will remember this when I need it.

Comment: @Thrakbad how we can get the items in that cutom layout for functioning?

Comment: Just add listeners etc in your onCreateOptionsMenu method or store a (weak) reference to the View there to be used later

Comment: but how? evem when I add OnClick method in header.xml file app crash and says can't find method.

Comment: Ah, sorry I didn't understand your question correctly. You can't use XML, you have to do it in your code. See my second edit above.

Answer (score 18):

Just use `orderInCategory` in your xml file and it will order from less number to greater (from left side of your action bar). Such as:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/Refresh"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_refresh"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="@string/refresh"
    android:orderInCategory="2"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/Search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_action_search"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
    android:title="@string/search"
    android:orderInCategory="1"/>
```

Even though, **Refresh** item is coming first in xml file, it won't be first. But **Search** icon from left to rigth in your action bar will be first according to its orderInCategory attribute.

Comment: easy and clear, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The order of the menu items will be set according to their order in the XML file that they are inflated.

Therefore all you need to do is change the order in the XML file as you like.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve it is by calling [invalidateOptionMenu](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#invalidateOptionsMenu%28%29) and in the [onCreateOptionsMenu](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreateOptionsMenu%28android.view.Menu%29) method, put the items according to the order you wish to put them.

BTW, if you use ActionBarSherlock, this method is available , so ignore the Lint warnings about it.

Comment: Can you guide me how to achieve this? Any sort of code will be help for me.

Comment: Yes, wherever you wish to change the order of the items, save the configuration of the order of the items, and call invalidateOptionMenu() . Then , in the onCreateOptionsMenu() method, check the configurations you've stored, and using a loop, go over all of the items you wish to insert by their order , and add them to the menu one by one, dynamically. You should do it by accessing the "menu" variable of onCreateOptionsMenu(). If you wish to contain "static" action items using inflate, that's ok, just find exactly where to put the rest inside the menu itself.