# Android floating menu on left to right swipe

Tags: android, contextmenu

I want to create a menu as shown in the picture in my application .So please tell me how to do this .Is there any library file is available for this.
 any help will be appreciable.

[image: see the floating menu at left side]

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16082440

Comment: hi that tutorial is about action bar .See the menu at left side of the image

Comment: do you try that, read all the comments and answer in that link too

Comment: @ArunAntoney have you got the solution. please share?

Comment: HI i got the answer you can use following project for help     https://github.com/lorensiuswlt/NewQuickAction3D

Answer (score 0):

You can use this example:

http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/

just you can shorten the animating view size in height wise as well as the width so you will be able to replicate the exact behavior what you want .

Hope this helps..